# I am getting ZeroDivisionError while dividing by squared argument

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a recursive function in python that keeps giving me a division by zero error, why am I getting this?

I've tried several rearrangements of if statements to eliminate all operations when n==0 but somehow it still occurs. I've added a `print(n)` to the else portion to see when the error occurs and it prints fine all the way to n=2, but then when n=1 it seems I get the error. This is strange because when I do `kleinfeldt(1)` it works fine...

```
def kleinfeldt(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return ((1/(n^2)) + kleinfeldt(n-1))
```

If I type in `kleinfeldt(3)` for example, I should get a result of 1 + 1/4 + 1/9, but instead it just says that there's a division by zero error.

Comment: as a token of appreciation for the help offered by the ones that answered please mark the answer that helped you most (gray tick mark on the left from the answer).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you confused the XOR operator (`^`) with power operator (`**`). The code works fine if change it:

```
def kleinfeldt(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return ((1/(n**2)) + kleinfeldt(n-1))
```

If you care about precise result you may want to read about [`fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed you will get an `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero` error because you are using an xor(`^`) operator in the below line of else condition :

```
return ((1/(n^2)) + kleinfeldt(n-1))
```

When it comes to the input 3, `2^2` will give you the `0` output so if you divide `1/(2^2)` you will get an error.

To avoid this, you can use `**` which will act as a power function or you can do like below :

```
import math
int(math.pow(2, 2))
```

Try the below modified codes :

```
def kleinfeldt(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return ((1/(n**2)) + kleinfeldt(n-1))
```

Or

```
import math
def kleinfeldt(n):
if n == 1:
    return 1
else:
    return ((1/(int(math.pow(n, 2)))) + kleinfeldt(n-1))
```

I hope it helps...